# Why does my bash script not complete when launhed from a Gnome shortcut in Fedora 31?

Tags: bash, fedora, gnome, usb

I use a USB Ethernet adapter here and it regularly falls out of my laptop and when I plug it in again sometimes Fedora 31 (or may laptop) doesn't recognise it has been plugged in again - resulting in me not being able to use the internet.

I created a script in C that resets the USB device and then created a bash script that runs the C file. That works fine. However, I'd like to add the script as a button to the Gnome launcher but for some reason although the shortcut launches the terminal, it does not complete and the terminal simply closes without resetting the USB device as intended.

I'm using the following launcher:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Reset Ethernet
Comment=Resets D-Link Ethernet USB Device
Exec=/home/me/Documents/linux/usbreset.sh
Terminal=true
Type=Application
```

This is the bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Reset specific USB Device
# currently set to specifically target D-Link Ethernet Adapter
device="2001:4a00"

regex="Bus ([0-9]+) Device ([0-9]+)"

getusb="$(lsusb -d ${device})"

if [[ ${getusb} =~ $regex ]]
then
    bus="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
#   echo "${bus}"  
    dev="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
#   echo "${dev}"  
else
    echo "no matching USB device found" 
fi

sudo ./usbreset /dev/bus/usb/${bus}/${dev}
```

Anyone know why this doesn't work?

Thanks

Comment: You call `./usbreset` in your script. Do you know what the current working directory is when you run it the launcher (I'm guessing it is your home directory, not `~/Documents/linux`)?

Comment: +1 fwiw I did a quick test on my Ubuntu box, and it seems to set the pwd to `~/Desktop`. Regardless, you should probably use an absolute path.